# User Dashboard not showing assigned groups

Tags: permissions, groups, backdrop

I have gone through the permissions, and I cannot find the one where users view their own groups, and the dashboard isn’t showing groups for logged in users.

I need this to be able to be viewed by all our members.

I am using Backdrop with CiviCRM 5.65.0
An Example of one of my groups is:
[image: Group Settings Example]

TIA

Comment: is it the 'visibility' setting on the Group itself, ie "Select 'User and User Admin Only' if joining this group is controlled by authorized CiviCRM users only. If you want to allow contacts to join and remove themselves from this group via the Registration and Account Profile forms, select 'Public Pages'.

"

Comment: Is 'Groups' ticked in your display preferences settings?

Comment: I have just added an example of my group settings.
I dont want the users to be able to add themselves, but i would like for them to be able to see what groups they are members of

Comment: Have you checked what Rebecca suggested, at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 there is a set of checkboxes that determine what entities show on the dashboard

Comment: Yes, groups is selected in the display preferences.